# Prove or Disprove: There are infinitely many integers $n$ such that the three integers $n$, $n+2$, $n+4$ are all prime.

Tags: prime-numbers

Prove or Disprove: There are infinitely many integers $n$ such that the three integers $n$, $n+2$,$n+4$ are all prime. (Suggestion: Try some sample values of $n$ and look for a pattern.)

Comment: At least one of them is multiple of 3.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion? It was a useful one.

Comment: I tried the suggestion. I think I was having trouble deciphering what the statement meant. ( I couldn't put it into if-then form )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, there is *only one* value of $n$ such that $n, n+2$, and $n+4$ are all prime, and that is $n=3$.  You have $3,5,7$ are all prime.

For all other values of $n$, you should notice that exactly one of them is divisible by three.  This needs to be proven however.

Break into cases:

- $n$ is a multiple of three.  I.e. $n=3k$ for some integer $k$.
- $n$ is one more than a multiple of three.  I.e. $n=3k+1$ for some integer $k$.
- $n$ is two more than a multiple of three.  I.e. $n=3k+2$ for some integer $k$.

Now, look at what each case would imply about $n, n+2, n+4$ and their divisibility by three.

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears it up perfectly.